# Trying to use dictionaries with user input (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, input

Can someone help me? I'm trying to figure out how to simplify this code. People have been suggestion using dictionaries but I can't figure out how. I just want to shorten the code and not use as many if statements. Also just to clarify, I want to have the user input a hero and have a different hero printed back.

```
choice = str(input('Choose a hero\n'))

def hero_choose():
    if choice.lower() == 'batman':
        return('Moon Knight')
    if choice.lower() == 'moon knight':
        return('Batman')
    if choice.lower() == 'superman':
        return('Hyperion')
    if choice.lower() =='hyperion':
        return('Superman')
    if choice.lower() == 'thor':
        return('Shazam')
    if choice.lower() == 'shazam':
        return('Thor')
    if choice.lower() == 'red hood':
        return('punisher')
    if choice.lower() == 'punisher':
        return('Red Hood')
    if choice.lower() == 'wonder woman':
        return('Jean Grey')
    if choice.lower() == 'jean grey':
        return('Wonder Woman')
    if choice.lower() == 'iron man':
        return('Batwing')
    if choice.lower() == 'batwing':
        return('Iron Man')
    if choice.lower() == 'flash':
        return('Quicksilver')
    if choice.lower() == 'quicksilver':
        return('Flash')
    else:
        return('Your hero may not be available\nor your spelling may be wrong.')

print(hero_choose())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary is definitely the best way to simplify this code. You can set up all the choices using the input as keys and use the default parameter to `dict.get` to return a message on error:

```
choice = str(input('Choose a hero\n'))

hero_choose = { 'batman' : 'Moon Knight', 
                'moon knight' : 'Batman',
                'superman' : 'Hyperion',
                'hyperion' : 'Superman'
                # ...
               }

hero = hero_choose.get(choice.lower(), 'Your hero may not be available\nor your spelling may be wrong.')

print(hero)
```

Comment: Note: Given all the pairings are mirrored, you could just make the (cased) pairings (half the length of the full `dict`), then construct a `dict` by mapping each pairing both ways, lower-casing it when it's a key. `pairs = (('Batman', 'Moon Knight'), ('Superman', 'Hyperion'), ...)`, then `hero_choose = {h1.lower(): h2 for pair in pairs for h1, h2 in (pair, pair[::-1])}`

Comment: @ShadowRanger for OPs sample data that is definitely a cool way of making the dict. I was going for a more general solution...

Answer (score -1):

You could also do this:

```
 hero_choices = { 'batman': 'Moon Knight',
                  'moon knight: 'Batman',
                  'superman':'Hyperion',
                  'hyperion': 'Superman',
                   ...
                }

 getChoice = str(input("Please choose a hero:\n"))


 for key, value in hero_choices.items():
    if key == "getChoice":
       print(hero_choices[key])
    elif key != "getChoice":
       print("This hero doesn't exist!")
```

This is an alternative solution to the one above.